# XCode 4 - Remove target membership for localization files

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have a project with two targets - one is for iPhone and the other is for iPad. The iPhone version is localized in 4 languages but the iPad version is not, even though it uses some strings from the iPhone version. I recently upgraded to XCode 4 and I'm trying to exclude two out of four localizations from the iPad target. It was possible with XCode 3 but with XCode 4 when I uncheck target membership for one of the localization files, all the other localization files also become unchecked. So it's all or nothing situation. Is there a way to exclude only certain localization files? Is it a bug or is this intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem .. I have a app which has many graphic assets so there are different versions for different markets. So I have a target for every localisation.

I had to put the string files to different folders, after that i could add the folders to their targets.

Maybe you can also split your localisations to two folders and add one only to the ipad target.

Comment: Good idea, I may have to end up creating a copy of each strings file and move them into a different folder as you suggest. I was hoping to use the same files for both targets as the strings are mostly the same.

Comment: you could probably just copy the languages you don't need in the ipad app to the other folder. then add the first folder to both and the second folder only to the iphone target

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating separate Resources directories for my iPhone and iPad targets - Resources-iPhone and Resources-iPad - and making two copies of each localization directory. For example I have Resources-iPhone/ja.lproj/Localizable.strings and Resources-iPad/ja.lproj/Localizable.strings. Now I can easily have two different sets of localized resources for my two targets. The downside is that now I have to maintain two copies of mostly identical strings file.